# Moving a bottom aligned widget up when showing Snackbar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is a simple problem I am facing

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => _showSnackbar(context),
              child: Text("show snackbar"),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showSnackbar(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context)
      ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("this is snackbar"),
      ));
  }
}
```

When the `Snackbar` is shown the `FloatingActionButton` moves up but the `RaisedButton` is hidden behind the `Snackbar`. How to make `Snackbar` not cover any widget when it is shown? In Android, I can use `CoordinatorLayout`. What should I do here?

[image: output of code]

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

So, this is the output of the below-mentioned source code: [View](https://www.veed.io/view/8c1d7f88-6d08-4efb-846e-86ad807c8fe4?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

Source code:

```
class SomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: const SafeArea(child: SizedBox()),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _showSnackbar(context);
              },
              child: const Text("Show snackbar"),
            ),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showSnackbar(BuildContext context) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    const SnackBar snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text("See, snackbar here!"));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
    return;
  }
}
```